# Centos8.1 on Virtual Box Yum Install Error

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I am trying to install Guest Additions on Oracle VirtualBox and needed to install gcc, perl, make, etc.  When doing so, I get the following error:

```
CentOS-8 - AppStream     0.0 B/s | 0 B 00:00
Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream'
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream'
```

My Host is MacOS Catalina.  Any idea about how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the following steps. (Added screenshot as well)

1. Go to Oracle VM settings and make sure the adapter is NAT
2. Start your machine
3. Go to settings -> Network -> click on the settings icon in "Wired"

- select the 3rd tab "IPv4"
- select Method as "Manual"
- Add the following data
- **Address = 10.0.2.3, Netmask = 255.255.255.0, gateway = 10.0.2.2, DNS = 8.8.8.8**

Note: T[image]his is because the Oracle VM default NAT is 10.0.2.2

Answer (score 3):

login as root

```
cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
vim ifcfg-enp0s3
```

ONBOOT=yes

```
:wq
reboot
```

https://superuser.com/questions/915536/centos-7-virtualbox-no-internet-access

Answer (score 0):

We just ran into this with one of our developers. the issue with their vm was simply that the vm was not connected to the internet- can you check and see if you are connected to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for me

1. Open Virtualbox Manager
2. Select the machine you cannot get internet on in the left pane
3. Click the Settings button in the top menu
4. Click Network in the left pane in the settings window
5. Switched to Bridged Adapter in the Attached to drop-down menu
6. Select the name of the network adapter you are currently using on your host machine. I 
   am using wireless so I chose eth0 which is my wireless network adapter. You can check 
   which adapter you are currently using by opening the terminal (CTRL+ALT+T by default) 
   and running ifconfig. It will probably be the eth adapter that shows an inet addr and 
   shows data transfer next to RX bytes.
7. Under Advanced, make sure the machine is using the Desktop Adapter Type
8. Under Advanced, make sure Promiscuous Mode is set to Allow VMs
9. Under Advanced, make sure Cable connected is checked on
10. Hit OK to save your changes
11. Start your VM

https://askubuntu.com/questions/363003/no-internet-connection-on-virtualbox-windows-7-as-guest-ubuntu-13-04-as-host